# How can I fix this linter Pylint install return error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I use *Visual Studio Code*. I am switching from Python 2.7 to Python 3.8. When attempting to install the linter *Pylint*, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint<2.0.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pylint<2.0.0
```

What can I do to get *Pylint* to install?

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Drq.png)

Comment: Do not add screenshots of text. Instead copy and paste that text in your answer.

Comment: What is your Python interpreter version? Why are you trying to install an old version of _pylint_? -- Probably those old versions of pylint ar enot compatible with your newer version of the Python interpreter.

Comment: thanks Sinoroc, it's vss code Automatic installer，in python2.7 version, This error occurs, when I switch to version python 3.8, it seems to be fine, and pylint can normally work, but i don't know why

Comment: Looks to me like versions of pylint `<2.0.0` are not compatible with _Python 3.8_. You might want to remove the `<2.0.0` version constraint on _pylint_.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like versions of *Pylint* earlier than *2.0.0* (`pylint < 2.0.0`) are not compatible with *Python 3.8*. You might want to remove the `<2.0.0` version constraint on *Pylint*, and try to install again.